# cassandra-driver-mapping: InvalidTypeException: Invalid 32-bits float value, expecting 4 bytes but got 6

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, mapping, datastax

As I got issues with `spring-data-cassandra` with `docker` as describer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108050/unable-to-connect-to-cassandra-from-docker-container-using-spring-data-cassandra?noredirect=1#comment69422977_41108050) I switched to use `com.datastax.cassandra` library for cassandra operations but I am getting issues while mapping the resulted object using `entity mapper` as per this [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/using/)

Here is my code ...

```
public String getUser(String userName) {
    Mapper<User> mapper = manager.mapper(User.class);
    User result = mapper.get(userName);  // no issue getting User
    String accountNum = result.getAccountId();
    return accountNum ;
}

public Account getAccount(String accountNum){
    Mapper<Account> mapper = manager.mapper(Account.class);
    Account account = mapper.get(accountNum); // getting error here
    return account;
}
```

Account.java

```
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {
    @PartitionKey
    private String accountNum;
    private String accountsubtype;
    private float currentbalance;
    private String customertype;
    private String firstname;
    private boolean isactive;
    private String payments;
    private String status;
    ....
    //Getters & Setters 
}
```

pom.xml dependecies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you show your account-table description?

Comment: Can you please share Cassandra and Connector Version?

Comment: I figure out what's the issue is after looking at Table schema and `cassandra  data tyes` to `java types` , my CQL datatype is `decimal` and java `float` so I changed `float` to `BigDecimal` and it worked well. Thanks for your time